# geschachtelte Klammern: gepaarter Schrägstrich zulässig?

Tags: punctuation, parenthesis

Im Falle geschachtelter Klammern empfiehlt der Duden, [...] innerhalb von (...) zu nutzen. [Beispiel](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/klammern):

> Mit dem Wort Bankrott (vom italienischen „banca rotta“ [zusammengebrochene Bank]) bezeichnet man die Zahlungsunfähigkeit.

Allerdings haben die eckigen Klammern in meinem (Software betreffenden, was allerdings nichts mit der Frage direkt zu tun hat) Text zu viele spezielle Bedeutungen (sowohl mathematisch, als auch im Fließtext, z.B. bei Zitaten). Ich glaubte bis vor kurzem, man könne in diesen Fällen auch Schrägstriche innendrin nutzen:

> Mit dem Wort Bankrott (vom italienischen „banca rotta“ /zusammengebrochene Bank/) bezeichnet man die Zahlungsunfähigkeit.

Einen offiziellen (oder halboffiziellen) Verweis auf die Regelung, man dürfe den Schrägstrich als Klammerzeichen für internes Paar Klammern nutzen, finde ich allerdings nicht mehr (außer im 19. Jh. /: ... :/, was aber veraltet ist). Kann jemand helfen?

Comment: Ich habe diese Form der Klammerung noch nie gesehen, und würde die Schrägstriche als Trennung von Alternativen lesen, a la Bier / Wein / Schnaps. Daher würde ich sie nicht zum Klammern verwenden --- zu verwirrend. Eckige Klammern sind ok und IMHO geläufig. Nicht jeder Text benutzt Zitate, und nicht jeder Leser ist Programmierer. Wenn es Dich stört, nimm doch einach noch mal runde Klammern.

Comment: Wie wäre es mit *(vom italienischen „banca rotta“ – zusammengebrochene Bank)* ?

Comment: Geschweifte Klammern { } könnten auch noch eine Möglichkeit sein.

Comment: @jonathan Wenn die Zielgruppe des Textes Programmierer (C, Java) sind, wären geschweifte Klammern eine ganz schlechte Idee, da sie mehr verwirren als helfen. Geschachtelte runde Klammern sind da kein Problem.

Comment: Wo ist das Problem bei geschachtelten Klammern, wenn es in der Heimat geschachtelter Klammern, der Mathematik, schon keine Probleme damit gibt?

Answer (score 5):

Außerhalb einiger weniger fachspezifischer Bedeutungen wie zum Beispiel der Darstellung von Phonemen in der Linguistik wird der Schrägstrich nicht als etwas öffnendes und schließendes wahrgenommen sondern als etwas, das eine Sache davor von einer danach abgrenzt. So ist es mir ergangen, als ich deinen Beispielsatz gelesen habe:

> Mit dem Wort Bankrott (vom italienischen „banca rotta“/zusammengebrochene Bank/**Hoppla, fehlt hier was?**) bezeichnet man die Zahlungsunfähigkeit. [Leerzeichen des Originals entfernt]

Eine andere häufige Verwendung des Schrägstriches, die du aber sicher auch nicht anklingen lassen wolltest, ist das Abgrenzen von Versen, wenn man aus Platzgründen keinen Zeilenumbruch einfügen kann oder will.

> Zufrieden jauchzet groß und klein / Hier bin ich Mensch, hier darf ich’s sein.

In beiden Fällen ist der Gegensatz davor/danach und nicht innen/außen (siehe auch diesen Beispielsatz). Der Schrägstrich kann also nicht in deinem Sinn verwendet werden, ohne den Leser oder die Leserin vorher darauf hinzuweisen.

---

Allerdings möchte ich auch dem Duden widersprechen, denn ich finde die Verschachtelung von runden und eckigen Klammern ebenfalls stilistisch unschön. Wohin soll das (also nur, wenn man es nicht vermeiden kann [muss das wirklich sein? {Ich sträube mich ja schon ein bisschen (Hab dich nicht so!)}]) führen? Für solche Fälle ist es, meines Erachtens, kein Problem einfach normale Klammern zu verschachteln – wenn es denn wirklich sein muss. Zum Beispiel habe ich an folgendem nichts auszuseten:

> Mit dem Wort Bankrott (vom italienischen „banca rotta“ (zusammengebrochene Bank)) bezeichnet man die Zahlungsunfähigkeit.

Es mag zwar nicht die höchste typographische Kunst sein aber zum Beispiel in wissenschaftlichen Texten durchaus vertretbar. Manchmal lassen sich solche Doppelklammern überhaupt nicht vermeiden wie in folgendem Beispiel aus der Chemie, in welchem die Klammern um das kursiv gesetzte R streng vorgeschrieben sind:

> Das gewünschte Produkt ((*R*)-2-phenylpropansäure) wurde in 99 % Ausbeute erhalten.

---

Wenn die Doppelklammervariante nicht die stilistisch schönste ist, wie umgehen? Ganz einfach: umformulieren oder andere Textauszeichnungen verwenden. In deinem Beispiel bietet sich das besonders gut an:

> Mit dem Wort *Bankrott* (vom italienischen *banca rotta*, auf Deutsch *zusammengebrochene Bank*) bezeichnet man die Zahlungsunfähigkeit.

Und schon ist mal die elende Krücke Doppelklammer los.

Comment: Bin mir nicht sicher ob das so richtig is, aber ich benutze da gern einen Gedankenstrich: `(vom italienischen „banca rotta“ - zusammengebrochene Bank)` (kann das jetzt im Kommentar nicht richtig darstellen, deshalb hier nur einen Bindestrich).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Gedankenstriche sind super!

Answer (score 2):

Keine Ahnung, ob das so richtig ist, aber ich benutze da gern einen Gedankenstrich:

> Mit dem Wort Bankrott (vom italienischen „banca rotta“ – zusammengebrochene Bank) bezeichnet man die Zahlungsunfähigkeit.

*Das ist ein `&ndash;` in HTML*.

Das ist vielleicht nicht korrekt, aber meiner Meinung nach sehr gut lesbar und eindeutig.

Answer (score 0):

Nun gibt es doch so wahnsinnig viele Klammer- (und als solche intuitiv wahrnehmbare weil linear-symmetrische) -Formen, sind die denn alle in Deiner Software schon belegt?:

([{<‹≺ ≻›>}])